# How to show different words in a sentence display different colours, what's the 'correct' way to mark-up (for HTML-email markup)

Tags: css, html-email

If I put in a new

tag eg:

```
<p>lorem ipsem blah blah blah <p class="special-colour">special phrase</p><p> lorem ipsem blah blah blah</p>
```

I get linefeeds which is not what I want.

Also do I need to explicitly return to the style that I was using or will it be assumed unless overridden by the class="foo-bar" attribute?

I realise that question probably goes to specificity which I'm yet to get on top of, since I don't really know what hierarchies naturally exist in HTML/CSS documents, I'm just wading into it all ATM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `<span>`:

```
<p>first part <span class="special-colour">special phrase</span><p> next part</p>
```

it's an "inline" element so will not cause a line feed.

And yes, the `next part` text will automatically "revert" to the style applied to the `p` element.

Your css for the `span` would be something like:

```
span.special-colour {
    color: #ff7766;
}
```

Also, I can tell you are a UK-English speaker - be very careful with your use of `color` vs. `colour` !

Comment: So is <span> safe in HTML-emails? Yes, I'm okay with that Aus English. Rarely does color catch me out. Border/Boarder did today though.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
<p class="special-colour">`special phrase</p>
```

use

```
<span class="special-colour">special phrase</span>
```

The `span` tag is rendered in-line with no line breaks.

Comment: Thanks that answered a persisting question: `what is the point of the <span> tag` for me too!

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this question as html-email. The only way to get it working would be to create a table with say  3 columns, Put the respective content in the three columns and then style the each `td` of the `table` giving the inline-css. There is no way you can achieve this in any other way.

Exernal CSS never works for html-emails.

Comment: What about using inline CSS styles? I know it's not pretty but surely it's better than using tables for styling?

Comment: off course only inline-styles will work for you to render your email correctly in all the mail clients.

Comment: Almost every HTML template I've examined and all the HTML Newsletters I'm subscribed to use inline CSS and/or a CSS declaration in the HTML header. This seems to be the way it is done. Is the '<span>' tag safe in an email, if so it's the solution I'm looking for. I know the some email newsletters I've looked at change the text colour do mid-sentence, across vertical lines as it were, and are therefore not using a table to do it.

Comment: span is also a workable. You can use<span style="color:#785876; font-family:Arial;border:1px solid 3333333;">blah blah blah</span>.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<span>` (possibly with a class, or you can define a general rule for all spans contained in a paragraph). You could also use `<strong>` or `<em>` if you want to give the word or phrase more weight or added importance, for example it is the main subject of the page. There is also `<i>` and `<b>` as well that can be used.

http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/ has more information about when to use each